# How to find the hidden special character in the string "Regre​ssion" C#

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, hidden-characters

In the string "Regre​ssion" there is a special character hidden whenever this comes to DB it is storing it as "Regre?ssion" how to remove the hidden special character.

Note: I have not typed the string I have copied it from my application which is causing the issue someone did the copy I don't know how they got this string.

Comment: I imagine it could be a french accent ?

Comment: you can refer "Normalization" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net